# Adding 1 to the position of an array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, addition, maze, subscript

Hello stack overflow people so I have a problem. I am writing a Maze Traversal in C++ for a school project and I've run into a wall. I have an algorithm that checks the different positions that I can move in the maze. My problem is that maze doesn't actually change positions even when (I did debugging) valid move returns true. Why not? (I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question but I would appreciate any help!) Thanks!!!

```
//Said algorithm

// 4. cycle through directions to move in until I find a possible move
    if (validMove(maze, y + 1, x))      // UP
        maze[y][x] = maze[y + 1][x];
    else if (validMove(maze, y, x + 1)) // RIGHT
        maze[y][x] = maze[y][x + 1];
    else if (validMove(maze, y - 1, x)) // DOWN
        maze[y][x] = maze[y - 1][x];
    else if (validMove(maze, y, x - 1)) // LEFT
        maze[y][x] = maze[y][x - 1];

//validMove func
bool validMove( char maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE], int y, int x)
{
   if (maze[y][x] == '.') {
      return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: This question needs some more context. Show more of where `maze` is created and used, and where (and how) you're checking whether it's changed.

Comment: `maze doesn't actually change positions`  Clarify what you mean by "change positions".  I just see an assignment being done.

Comment: You're never actually changing the values of `x` or `y` - you're changing the content of the maze, which is probably not what you want. If, for example, "UP" is a valid move, you're replacing the current cell in the maze with the content of the cell above it (except for boundary conditions, which hopefully you're checking for elsewhere, otherwise `x + 1` and other such expressions might be accessing outside your maze...

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that a '.' in the maze indicates an open space and any other character indicates a wall. I also assume that x and y indicate your current position.

It looks like you are testing if you can go to a certain space, if it is possible, you then set the character in your current space equal to the character in the space you want to move into (I don't think you meant to do this). Since both characters are probably '.', this doesn't actually change anything.

I am guessing that you actually would like to leave a trail for yourself by changing the current position's character to a special character (to indicate the path you took) and then change your x and y to the new values of x and y.

```
maze[y][x] = '+';
if (validMove(maze, y + 1, x))      // UP
    y += 1;
else if (validMove(maze, y, x + 1)) // RIGHT
    x += 1;
else if (validMove(maze, y - 1, x)) // DOWN
    y -= 1;
else if (validMove(maze, y, x - 1)) // LEFT
    x -= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you probably should be maintaining a `position` variable, `std::pair` possibly, which would be the coordinate of your traversal in the maze.

So I'd expect your if statement to look more like this:

```
if (validMove(maze, y + 1, x))      // UP
    position.first++;
else if (validMove(maze, y, x + 1)) // RIGHT
   position.second++;
else if (validMove(maze, y - 1, x)) // DOWN
    position.first--;
else if (validMove(maze, y, x - 1)) // LEFT
    position.second--;
```

The only way you'd see this effecting anything is if in your print loop that outputs the array you added:

```
cout << (y == position.first && x == position.second) ? 'x' : maze[y][x];
```